# Why is kazoku/family used twice in this sentence?

Tags: counters

The exercise was to translate: "we are 6 in my family"
The answer given is: "watashi no kazoku wa roku-nin kazoku desu"

I can understand the role of all words except for the second occurrence of kazoku. As far as I can tell the sentence is complete without it..
"Watashi no kazoku" = "my family"
"Wa roku-nin" = "has 6 people"

Perhaps I am  misunderstanding the way the nin counter is used?

(If anyone uses Japanese characters in the reply... I can only read hirigana)

Comment: Even a direct translation of "Watashi no kazoku ha roku-nin desu" would be strange. "My family is 6 people".

Comment: Can someone explain why "Watashi no kazoku wa roku-nin desu" is bad/strange/wrong?  It sounds perfectly fine to me...  It just sounds like a simple omission like, "A:  Watashi wa Tokyo ni sunde imasu.  B-san wa?  B:  Watashi wa Osaka desu."

Answer (score 5):

The thing is translating words for words never works (at least from English to Japanese).

Here you put *watashi no kazoku* as your theme. The notion of theme can be roughly rendered here as follows: "As for my family".
Then, you describe the theme by saying: *roku-nin kazoku desu* (it's a family with 6 persons).

So what you are saying is: "As for my family, it is a 6-person family". If you were to remove the second *kazoku*, you would get: "As for my family, it is 6 persons" (which is understandable but no so good). On the other side, if the context was clear you could safely remove *watashi no kazoku* and it would still mean: "There is 6 members in my family". But without additional context, *watashi no kazoku wa roku-nin kazoku desu* is perfectly fine in itself.

Comment: On a side note could one say: "Watashi no kazoku ni roku-nin ga imasu."?

Comment: Or 「うちは 6人家族 です。」 (Uchi wa roku-nin kazoku desu).

Comment: @Leo; It means "Aforementioned 6 people are actually all from my family". What you might want is "watashi no kazoku wa 6 nin imasu".